# python threading.timer did not repeat function

Tags: python

I need write a function could repeat another function many times. I am using `threading.Timer` but it could not work.

Here ismy code:

```
import threading

def plus(a,b):
    print (a+b)

def repeat(func,interval,*args):
    threading.Timer(interval, func, args = args).start()

repeat(plus,1,2,3)
```

Comment: I read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) and I don't see where it says it should  repeat. In all likelyhood, you need to set a new timer in the thread function.

Answer (score 0):

To make it repeat, you need to setup a new timer after each interval.

One way to do it, although its a bit functional. It may not be the simplest way.

```
from threading import Timer
from functools import partial

def plus(a,b):
    print (a+b)

def repeat(func,interval,*args):

    # call the provided func
    func(*args)

    Timer(interval, partial(repeat, func, interval), args=args).start()

repeat(plus,1,2,3)
```

In `repeat` call your function, then setup the timer. You need to provide the correct arguments  to `interval`, so we need to partially apply it to already have the first two arguments.